# How does the function detectMSERFeatures in matlab work?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, mser

It is known that the [Maximally Stable Extremal Regions (MSERs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions) can found from an image in MATLAB using [`detectMSERFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html), and the outputs of this function are some MSERs.

But i have one questions which have confused me for a very long time, that is, why do some MSERs may contain some other MSERs in the output MSERs? Such as, three outputs MSERs, `m1`, `m2`, and `m3` may have the relationship, `m1` ∈ `m2` ∈ `m3`

Answer (score 2):

There is a section in the detectMSERFeatures documentation (under the More About section) that may help you better understand the algorithm:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html

You can get nested regions when you have an image intensity profile that that looks like a "V". If you use the bucket filling analogy from the documentation, then as you start to slowly pour water into the "V", stable regions will begin to appear and will be labeled as an MSER region. As you continue pouring water, larger stable regions will form and they will contain the previously found MSER regions.

Comment: Thank you very much!but I still have a question, suppose we have got three MSERs(m1,m2,m3),then they may have the nested relationship,such as m1∈m2∈m3,for m1 or m3, is there any technical term to describe them, such as the Maximum MSER or Minimal MSER? In fact I only need m1 and m3, which are the maximum and minimum respectively. Thank you again for your answer.